# cpanel nameserver not working

Tags: server, dns, domain-server

I have a main domain called nube22.com
domain registar: route53 
nameserver: self-generated in aws.
Record A named nube22.com: to point a "server 1"

I configured my own nameserver with cpanel on "Server 2". 
ns1.nube22.com 
ns2.nube22.com

On route53 with nube22.com I add two A records: ns1 and ns2 pointing to ip server 2

When I want to use my nameserver (ns1.nube22.com and ns2.nube22.com) for enlanuve.com (domain register www.domain.com) it say the nameserver is invalid.
What's wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Do you get any more detailed error messages?

Comment: if I use MXTOOLBOX for test. I get "Primary Name Server Not Listed At Parent
ns1.nube22.com"

Answer (score 0):

`ns1.nube22.com` is not configured correctly as a NS for `enlanuve.com`.

```
$ dig enlanuve.com @ns1.nube22.com SOA

; <<>> DiG 9.11.2 <<>> enlanuve.com @ns1.nube22.com SOA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: REFUSED, id: 60828
;; flags: qr rd; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 0, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1
;; WARNING: recursion requested but not available

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 4096
; COOKIE: 4dc7b42ecf42a59092bb78a15e08eaa92f3bb3e033f890d3 (good)
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;enlanuve.com.                  IN      SOA

;; Query time: 147 msec
;; SERVER: 18.216.94.141#53(18.216.94.141)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 29 19:04:25 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 69
```

It replies blank when asked for `SOA` record. Compare this with a properly configured domains reply for `SOA`:

```
$ dig example.com SOA

; <<>> DiG 9.11.2 <<>> example.com SOA
;; global options: +cmd
;; Got answer:
;; ->>HEADER<<- opcode: QUERY, status: NOERROR, id: 50770
;; flags: qr rd ra ad; QUERY: 1, ANSWER: 1, AUTHORITY: 0, ADDITIONAL: 1

;; OPT PSEUDOSECTION:
; EDNS: version: 0, flags:; udp: 1452
;; QUESTION SECTION:
;example.com.                   IN      SOA

;; ANSWER SECTION:
example.com.            1581    IN      SOA     ns.icann.org. noc.dns.icann.org. 2019121308 7200 3600 1209600 3600

;; Query time: 27 msec
;; SERVER: 1.1.1.1#53(1.1.1.1)
;; WHEN: Sun Dec 29 19:05:08 CET 2019
;; MSG SIZE  rcvd: 96
```

Before changing name server, you have to configure your nameserver(s) to correctly reply to queries for the domain.